# Download multiple selected files from library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, file, download

I have SharePoint 2016 on-premises.

The purpose is to download multiple selected files from a library, because some of my colleagues work at home, with no link to our LAN (so the Open in Windows Explorer doesn't work).

Is it possible to do something for that? It could be direct download or a single zip file download.